# Java 8 lambdas that access instance fields and methods can't be deserialized

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, deserialization, java-8

It seems to me it's a bug in the compiler or in the JVM, but maybe someone has a better explanation.

The following code runs fine as is, but if I uncomment the second `runnable` initialization, that uses 'this' directly, it can't deserialize the object (`in.readObject()` throws an exception).

```
public class TestClass implements Serializable {
    String               msg = "HEY!";
    SerializableRunnable runnable;
    public TestClass() {
        TestClass self = this;
        runnable = () -> self.say();  // uses a local copy of 'this'
       // runnable = () -> this.say(); // uses 'this' directly
    }
    public void say() {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer)) {
            out.writeObject(new TestClass());
        }
        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray()))) {
            TestClass s = (TestClass) in.readObject();
            s.say();
        }
    }
}
interface SerializableRunnable extends Runnable, Serializable {
}
```

This is the stacktrace for the root cause:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid lambda deserialization
    at j8test.TestClass.$deserializeLambda$(TestClass.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(SerializedLambda.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1104)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1810)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at j8test.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:30)
```

Is it the expected behavior?

Comment: Side comment: you don't need the extra interface, you can simply write: `Runnable runnable = (Runnable & Serializable) () -> self.say();`

Comment: I know. I just wanted to make it clear the thing is Serializable, and it was not another 'how can I serialize lambdas' question. not clear enough, it seems :)

Comment: I tried everything but the most obvious. The problem happens in Eclipse (wherein the java 8 support is still in beta), but not in javac. Thus, a JDT bug.

Comment: Works for me (in Eclipse). Are you sure you run the most recent version? There were lambda serialization bugs in the past, I filed some of them to the Eclipse team by myself, but they were fixed quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried everything but the most obvious.

The problem happens in Eclipse (wherein the java 8 support is still in beta), but not in javac. Thus, a JDT bug.

**[EDIT]**

I'm running:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java and Report Developers
Version: Luna RC1 Release (4.4.0RC1)
Build id: 20140522-1310

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

OS X 10.9.3
```

Maybe it's already corrected in a more recent build.

Comment: Is this a case for deleting the question myself?

Comment: You should leave it in case somebody comes across the same issue. You should accept your own answer though.

Comment: When talking about bugs in a software you should always add precise version information. With `Kepler SR2 + Eclipse JDT/Java 8 support 1.0.0.v20140317-1956` your example works without problems.

Comment: @Holger Yes! Well observed. I've edited the answer to add the information. thx

Comment: I'm using Eclipse SDK Version: Luna SR2 (4.4.2) Build id: M20141210-0900 and this has been fixed.

Comment: The fix is scheduled to SR2 indeed. It is planned to ship at the end of jan/15. A partial fix already shipped on an incremental update. Thanks for the update @RobertBain

Comment: Thanks @tetsuo. I've been having further problems that aren't fixed by the maintenance fix. Do you have any insight as to whether they might be fixed in SR2? My problems are documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488567/invalid-lambda-deserialization

Comment: I'm following these issues on Eclipse's tracker: [442416](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442416), [442418](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442418), and [449467](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=449467), all targeting 4.4.2/4.5.

Answer (score 3):

That is... rather odd.

This is what [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#serialization) says about serializing lambdas:

> You can serialize a lambda expression if its target type and its captured arguments are serializable. However, like inner classes, the serialization of lambda expressions is strongly discouraged.

I am not fully familiar with the captured arguments, but I am assuming that it is referring to all the elements that are being captured by the lambda, meaning in this case that it refers `this`, so it is a captured element then.

When further exploring that path, we see that `TestClass` needs to be serializable, which it seems to be as it implements `Serializable`. Moreover it will use the default lambda serialization (which is moreoften than not not a good idea), and it has as arguments a `String` and a `SerializableRunnable`, which both are `Serializable` again.

So it seems to me that you've hit a bug in the JVM and it could be caused by the target being equal to a captured argument (`this`).

Comment: I don’t get what you mean with your statement that using “default lambda serialization” is “moreoften than not a good idea”. There is no choice about how to serialize a lambda.