# java.lang.ClassCastException using lambda expressions in spark job on remote server

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda, java-8, spark-java

I'm trying to build a web api for my apache spark jobs using sparkjava.com framework. My code is:

```
@Override
public void init() {
    get("/hello",
            (req, res) -> {
                String sourcePath = "hdfs://spark:54310/input/*";

                SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("LineCount");
                conf.setJars(new String[] { "/home/sam/resin-4.0.42/webapps/test.war" });
                File configFile = new File("config.properties");

                String sparkURI = "spark://hamrah:7077";

                conf.setMaster(sparkURI);
                conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
                JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                JavaRDD<String> log = sc.textFile(sourcePath);

                JavaRDD<String> lines = log.filter(x -> {
                    return true;
                });

                return lines.count();
            });
}
```

If I remove the lambda expression or put it inside a simple jar rather than a web service (somehow a servlet) it will run without any error. But using a lambda expression inside a servlet will result this exception:

```
15/01/28 10:36:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, hamrah): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1.f$1 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

P.S: I tried combination of jersey and javaspark with jetty, tomcat and resin and all of them led me to the same result.

Comment: @pzecevic I'm trying to use a combination of apache spark and spark java and the error above occurs only in combination of them. Without this combination everything works fine.

Comment: I see. Maybe you could file a JIRA or ask the question at Apache Spark user list?

Comment: Strange. Looks like it’s not respecting the `readResolve` method of the `SerializedLambda`. Would be interesting if it fails for ordinary objects with a `readResolve` method too.

Comment: @Holger I've got the same problem, cloud you please explain more?

Comment: @Khajavi: Serializable lambda instances use `witeReplace` to substitute themselves with a [`SerializedLambda`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html) instance in the stream. `SerializedLambda` has a `readResolve` method to do the opposite when restoring. `witeReplace` and `readResolve` are [built-in features of Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Comment: Are you per chance using a different compilers dependent upon what you're building? I know there are some outstanding issues with the Eclipse JDT compiler surrounding lamda deserialisation. I created this post based on the problems I was having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488567/invalid-lambda-deserialization/27502424#27502424

Comment: @RobertBain The very same code works outside servlet context. If it was a problem with eclipse it would be at any circumstance.

Comment: so, what you're saying is that replacing the lambda with a plain old anonymous class would work as expected?

Comment: I think this bug is related. If I replaced my lambdas to anonym classes, it worked for me. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8024931

Answer (score 64, accepted):

What you have here, is a follow-up error which masks the original error.

When lambda instances are serialized, they use `writeReplace` to dissolve their JRE specific
implementation from the persistent form which is a [`SerializedLambda`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html)
instance. When the `SerializedLambda` instance has been restored, its `readResolve` method will be invoked
to reconstitute the appropriate lambda instance. As the documentation says, it will do so by invoking a special method of the class which defined the original lambda (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084460/2711488)). The important point is that the original class is needed and that’s what’s missing in your case.

But there’s a …special… behavior of the `ObjectInputStream`. When it encounters an exception, it doesn’t bail out immediately. It will record the exception and continue the process, marking all object being currently read, thus depending on the erroneous object as being erroneous as well. Only at the end of the process it will throw the original exception it encountered. What makes it so strange is that it will also continue trying to set the fields of these object. But when you look at the method `ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject` line 1806:

```
…
    if (obj != null &&
        handles.lookupException(passHandle) == null &&
        desc.hasReadResolveMethod())
    {
        Object rep = desc.invokeReadResolve(obj);
        if (unshared && rep.getClass().isArray()) {
            rep = cloneArray(rep);
        }
        if (rep != obj) {
            handles.setObject(passHandle, obj = rep);
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

you see that it doesn’t call the `readResolve` method when `lookupException` reports a non-`null` exception. But when the substitution did not happen, it’s not a good idea to continue trying to set the field values of the referrer but that’s exactly what’s happens here, hence producing a `ClassCastException`.

You can easily reproduce the problem:

```
public class Holder implements Serializable {
    Runnable r;
}
public class Defining {
    public static Holder get() {
        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        holder.r=(Runnable&Serializable)()->{};
        return holder;
    }
}
public class Writing {
    static final File f=new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "x.ser");
    public static void main(String... arg) throws IOException {
        try(FileOutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(f);
            ObjectOutputStream   oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os)) {
            oos.writeObject(Defining.get());
        }
        System.out.println("written to "+f);
    }
}
public class Reading {
    static final File f=new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "x.ser");
    public static void main(String... arg) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try(FileInputStream is=new FileInputStream(f);
            ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(is)) {
            Holder h=(Holder)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(h.r);
            h.r.run();
        }
        System.out.println("read from "+f);
    }
}
```

Compile these four classes and run `Writing`. Then delete the class file `Defining.class` and run `Reading`. Then you will get a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field test.Holder.r of type java.lang.Runnable in instance of test.Holder
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
```

(Tested with 1.8.0_20)

---

The bottom line is that you may forget about this Serialization issue once it is understood what’s happening, all you have to do for solving your problem is to make sure that the class which defined the lambda expression is also available in the runtime where the lambda is deserialized.

Example for Spark Job to run directly from IDE (spark-submit distributes jar by default):

```
SparkConf sconf = new SparkConf()
  .set("spark.eventLog.dir", "hdfs://nn:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory")
  .set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
  .setJars(new String[]{"/path/to/jar/with/your/class.jar"})
  .setMaster("spark://spark.standalone.uri:7077");
```

Comment: You said `all you have to do for solving your problem is to make sure that the class which defined the lambda expression is also available in the runtime where the lambda is deserialized.`, Can you tell me ho it can be done. Can you give an example?

Comment: @ѕтƒ Just invoke `setJars(new String[]{"/path/to/jar/with/your/class.jar"})` on your SparkConf instance if you run code from IDE like Idea. `spark-submit` distributes your jar by default, so there're no such issues

Comment: @Holger - amazing! :) Out of curiosity, how does it work for lambdas defined in the Spark shell/repl? I imagine the defining class for those is anonymous but somehow they get deserialized too?

Comment: @George I’m not involved in the development of Spark, so I don’t know. But I can imagine that the shell remembers the definitions you’ve entered, which is a transferable form, sufficient to replicate the code on the other side. So only the code of the shell resp. of its backend needs to be available on the other side.

Comment: Excellent analysis, well done! IMHO that *speshul* behavior in fact secretly swallows exceptions, which is a big fat antipattern and something that definitely shouldn't be lurking in JVM's code. Perhaps we should post a bug report?

Comment: @MartinVysny it’s so long ago, I can’t remember why I didn’t. Perhaps, because I was aware of [this fundamental issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8024931) and thought, it’s broken anyway. But since the issue of this answer is avoidable, posting a bug report makes sense. I’ll check whether there is an existing one and file a new one if not.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error and I replaced the lambda with an inner class, then it worked. I don't really understand why, and reproducing this error was extremely difficult (we had one server which exhibited the behavior, and nowhere else).

**Doesn't work**

```
this.variable = () -> { ..... }
```

Yields `java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field MyObject.val$variable`

**Works**

```
this.variable = new MyInterface() {
    public void myMethod() {
       .....
    }
};
```

Comment: same here, replaced with an anon clase and works, i dont have problems with the jar because jar was sended to spark in configuration, dont know whats is causing this behavior with lambdas

Comment: in my case is very weird, because only dont work with a specific lambda of type FilterFunction, other lambdas in the same class works fine

Comment: This solved the problem for me too

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your problem is failed auto-boxing. In the code

```
x -> {
      return true;
}
```

you pass (`String->boolean`) lambda (it is `Predicate<String>`) while [filter method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#filter(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)) takes (`String->Boolean`) lambda (it is `Function<String,Boolean>`). So I offer you to change code to

```
x -> {
      return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

Include details into your question please. Output from `uname -a` and `java -version` is appreciated. Provide [sscce](http://sscce.org/) if possible.

Comment: I think you miss the note that "If I put it inside a simple jar rather than a web service (somehow a servlet) it will run without any error".

Comment: @SAM I've read this part. I supposed this is either error in servlet or or java. I offer you to change the code *not to fix problem in your code* but *to workaround environment problem*.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe more simply remplace your Java8 lambda with a `spark.scala.Function`

replace

```
output = rdds.map(x->this.function(x)).collect()
```

with:

```
output = rdds.map(new Function<Double,Double>(){

   public Double call(Double x){
       return MyClass.this.function(x);
   }

}).collect();
```