# Spark - java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8

```
public class SparkDemo {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark APP").setMaster("spark://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:7077");

        
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("/Users/mchaurasia/file.txt");

        JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap((String s) -> {
            return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
        });

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair((String s) -> {
            return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
        });

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);

        for (Tuple2<String, Integer> result : counts.collect()) {
            System.out.println(result._1 + " , " + result._2);
        }

        sc.close();
        System.out.println("================= DONE ===================");
    }
```

**The above code is working fine when I set master to local(setMaster("local")), when I use setMaster("spark://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:7077"),**
I am getting following error --

```
6/06/21 09:28:59 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, xxx.xxx.xxx.xx): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.f$3 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)


Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, xxx.xxx.xxx.xx): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.f$3 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
```

Comment: Check that the class containing the lambda expression, i.e. `SparkDemo` is available on the remote side. The `ClassCastException` is an old Serialization issue that appears as follow-up exception hiding the actual cause, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28186607/2711488).

Comment: And this issue is still not fixed after 8 years?