# How to use lambda expression in java8 so that it can run on spark

Tags: apache-spark, lambda, java-8

I'm learning spark2.1.0, and I'm now writing spark WordCount on eclipse.
My spark in running on remote machine and its name is **c1**. The master is `spark://c1:7077`
My file is on hadoop2.3.7. The input file is on `hdfs://c1:9000/tmp/README.md`

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "hdfs://c1:9000/tmp/README.md"; 
        String output = "hdfs://c1:9000/tmp/output";

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Word Count").setMaster("spark://c1:7077");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile(input);
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = textFile
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator())
                .mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1))
                .reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);
        counts.saveAsTextFile(output);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

When I run it on my eclipse, I encountered the problem.

```
17/03/12 22:25:50 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.122.2, executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.f$3 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2237)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2122)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I searched this problem on google. I find the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935401/spark-java-lang-classcastexception-cannot-assign-instance-of-java-lang-invoke#comment63332988_37935401). In the comment I saw `Check that the class containing the lambda expression, i.e. SparkDemo is available on the remote side.`. I can not understand this sentence. I can only run my program on the spark machine? So I have to copy my program to **c1** and run the program on **c1**?

So my question is:
How can I run my program on my computer not on **c1**?

I don't think my question is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607). The answer which get 19 supports explain how do that problem occur. Then I tried using setJars method but the problem still exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException using lambda expressions in spark job on remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607/java-lang-classcastexception-using-lambda-expressions-in-spark-job-on-remote-ser)

Comment: I don't think my question is duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607). The answer which get 19 supports explain how do that problem occur. Then I tried using setJars method but the problem still exist.

Comment: As that answer explains, the `ClassCastException` is a Serialization artifact that occurs after another exception. While a missing class seems to be a common source, it is still possible that it is a different exception in your case. The bad news is that we have no chance of finding out by only looking at the exception that masks the original exception. You have to do your own investigation to find the actual cause. It’s easy to check whether the issue lies in finding the class by replacing the lambda expressions with inner classes and try to run and see if you get an appropriate exception…