# Error on running Spark application on remote Spark cluster using IDE

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have a Spark application that read data from Kafka and do processing. Creating a fat jar using maven and command: `mvn clean compile assembly:single`, I can successfully submit it to a Spark remote cluster with `spark-submit` command tool(No Yarn, just standalone cluster). Now I try to run the same application without generating fat jar and directly from IntelliJ IDE. After I run the application in IDE it submit a job in cluster's Master but after a while errors:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDPartition
```

I think dependencies in POM.xml file are not accessible for Spark application.

Here is the POM.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Saprk</groupId>
    <artifactId>SparkPMUProcessing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>SparkTest</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Point:** I have the same problem running Apache Flink application on the remote cluster. Flink as well as Spark, Run correctly using the fat jar and terminal command to submit to the cluster.

**Update:** Using method `setJars` I introduce dependency jar files and the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:` error type disapeared. Now it says:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.fun$1 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1
```

Here is my code:

```
    public class SparkTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("PMUStreaming").setMaster("spark://namenode1:7077")
                .set("spark.deploy.mode", "client")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "700m").setJars(new String[]{
                        "/home/xxx/SparkRunningJars/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0.jar",
                        "/home/xxx/SparkRunningJars/kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar",
                        "/home/xxx/SparkRunningJars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar"
                });
        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();

        Collection<String> TOPIC = Arrays.asList(args[6]);
        final String BOOTSTRAPSERVERS = args[0];
        final String ZOOKEEPERSERVERS = args[1];
        final String ID = args[2];
        final int BATCH_SIZE = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        final String PATH = args[4];
        final String READMETHOD = args[5];

        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAPSERVERS);
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", ID);
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", READMETHOD);
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.max.age.ms", 30000);

        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(BATCH_SIZE));
        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                ssc,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, byte[]>Subscribe(TOPIC, kafkaParams)
        );


        stream.map(record -> getTime(record.value()) + ":"
                + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ":"
                + Arrays.deepToString(finall(record.value()))
                + ":" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .map(record -> record + ":"
                        + Long.toString(Long.parseLong(record.split(":")[3]) - Long.parseLong(record.split(":")[1])))
                .repartition(1)
                .foreachRDD(new VoidFunction2<JavaRDD<String>, Time>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd, Time time) throws Exception {
                        if (rdd.count() > 0) {
                            rdd.saveAsTextFile(PATH + "/" + time.milliseconds());
                        }
                    }
                });
        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this answer? It might help.

[java.lang.ClassCastException using lambda expressions in spark job on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607/java-lang-classcastexception-using-lambda-expressions-in-spark-job-on-remote-ser/28367602#28367602)

> Just invoke setJars(new String[]{"/path/to/jar/with/your/class.jar"}) on your SparkConf instance if you run code from IDE like Idea. spark-submit distributes your jar by default, so there're no such issues

**UPDATE**
You have to add the jar of your project as well.

So the code should be

```
public class SparkTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("PMUStreaming").setMaster("spark://namenode1:7077")
                .set("spark.deploy.mode", "client")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "700m").setJars(new String[]{
                        "/home/xxx/SparkRunningJars/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0.jar",
                        "/home/xxx/SparkRunningJars/kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar",
                        "/home/xxx/SparkRunningJars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.0.jar",
                        "/path/to/your/project/target/SparkPMUProcessing-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
                });
        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();

        Collection<String> TOPIC = Arrays.asList(args[6]);
        final String BOOTSTRAPSERVERS = args[0];
        final String ZOOKEEPERSERVERS = args[1];
        final String ID = args[2];
        final int BATCH_SIZE = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        final String PATH = args[4];
        final String READMETHOD = args[5];

        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAPSERVERS);
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", ID);
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", READMETHOD);
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.max.age.ms", 30000);

        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(BATCH_SIZE));
        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                ssc,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, byte[]>Subscribe(TOPIC, kafkaParams)
        );


        stream.map(record -> getTime(record.value()) + ":"
                + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ":"
                + Arrays.deepToString(finall(record.value()))
                + ":" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .map(record -> record + ":"
                        + Long.toString(Long.parseLong(record.split(":")[3]) - Long.parseLong(record.split(":")[1])))
                .repartition(1)
                .foreachRDD(new VoidFunction2<JavaRDD<String>, Time>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd, Time time) throws Exception {
                        if (rdd.count() > 0) {
                            rdd.saveAsTextFile(PATH + "/" + time.milliseconds());
                        }
                    }
                });
        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add the jar of your project as well in `setJars`. I updated the answer with the correct code.

Comment: You're right. I had tried that but I want to be able changing the code without generating a new jar of classes each time!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my build.sbt dependencies. It's sbt configuration but you can recognize what you need to specify dependencies.

```
lazy val commonLibraryDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% f"spark-streaming-kafka-$kafkaVersion" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% f"spark-sql-kafka-$kafkaVersion" % sparkVersion,
)
```

Comment: I know what dependencies I do need and I can run the fat jar correctly. My problem is I can't run my code on IDE!