# java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD

Tags: apache-spark

Following is my simple code. When I run it in Spark Local mode it runs perfectly. But when I Try to run it in cluster mode with 1 driver and 1 worker it gives me following exception.

I have tried setJars which is mentioned in some answers but it hasn't helped me.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("example.ClusterPractice").setMaster("spark://192.168.42.18:7077");
        conf.setJars(new String[]{"E:\\Eclipses\\neon new projects\\eclipse\\neon new projects\\spark-practice\\out\\artifacts\\spark_practice_jar\\spark-practice.jar"});

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<Integer> numbers = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

        System.out.println("Reduce");
        long total = numbers.reduce((n1,n2)-> n1+n2);
        System.out.println(total);
    }
```

Exception I am getting is as follows :

> Driver stacktrace:
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1602)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>       at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1823)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1772)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2131)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1029)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1011)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.reduce(JavaRDDLike.scala:385)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.reduce(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
>       at example.ClusterPractice.main(ClusterPractice.java:22)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction2$1.fun$2 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2 in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction2$1
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2251)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above program works perfectly.

The issue was in building the jar. So don't doubt the program just focus on whether jar is getting built properly or not.

In my case, I am using Intellij. I was doing build artifact from build option and I think due to it jar was not getting built properly as it is maven project.

So, when I did maven build jar got built properly and program ran smoothly.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail how you built the jar in Java project for Spark ?

Answer (score 3):

You can find detailed answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28367602/1266150)

It seems you are **removing** the jars that has been set using

`conf.setJars(new String[]{"E:\\Eclipses\\neon new projects\\eclipse\\neon new projects\\spark-practice\\out\\artifacts\\spark_practice_jar\\spark-practice.jar"});`

from the configuration with this line

`conf.setJars(new String[]{""});`

**Remove** this line and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Sorry, That line was placed there mistakenly. But after removing it as well. It is not working.

Comment: This response was for the original question before it was updated. Why was it changed from acceptable to not acceptable ?