# What causes ClassCastException when serializing TypeTags?

Tags: java, scala, serialization, jvm

### Situation

I'm serializing an implementation of this class:

```
abstract class FnDescriptor[T <: FnRequest: TypeTag, R <: FnResponse: TypeTag] with Serializable {

  override type Input  = T
  override type Output = R
  override type State  = S

  val inputTag: TypeTag[Input]   = implicitly[TypeTag[T]]
  val outputTag: TypeTag[Output] = implicitly[TypeTag[R]]

}
```

and sending it over REST to a Gateway, which reads it to find the types of input and output state. (Yes I know this isn't a great design)

### Results

Now if I run a test, launching both the gateway and the requester who serializes the FnNamespace everything goes fine.

If however I launch the executables separately, that is the gateway in an executable and the requester in another, I get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.reflect.api.SerializedTypeTag to field com.package.structure.FnDescriptor.inputTag of type scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag in instance of com.package.structure.FnDescriptor$$anon$1

### Clues

The research I've done says that the Serializer transformed the TypeTag to a SerializedTypeTag using the writeReplace method. A corresponding readResolve should happen at the deserializer to transform the SerializedTypeTag back to a TypeTag, but it does not happen. Instead it tries to assign a SerializedTypeTag to a TypeTag causing the exception.

The fact that it doesn't happen in a single JVM is the best clue I have, though I don't know how to interpret it.

### Full stacktrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.reflect.api.SerializedTypeTag to field com.package.structure.FnDescriptor.inputTag of type scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag in instance of com.package.structure.FnDescriptor$$anon$1
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2293)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1975)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at com.package.structure.gateway.GatewayService$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(GatewayService.scala:76)
```

Comment: Compare with [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28186607/2711488). You may have a similar kind of problem, i.e. it may be a follow-up of an exception that occurred before, or you have a cyclic object graph. Object replacements and cyclic graphs do not play well together. That’s a fundamental limitation of the Serialization framework.

Comment: This could well be the cause. But that would mean that TypeTags are not "sharable". What should one do to share a class definition with another JVM, when the other has never seen that class?

Comment: That’s not an issue of the TypeTags. First, you have to identify the original cause of the problem. E.g., use a debugger to identify all exceptions that were thrown and caught before the `ClassCastException`.