# Sprint boot service connecting to Spark remote cluster - java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda

Tags: apache-spark

I have a 3 node spark cluster setup:

192.168.1.1 (master and slave)

192.168.1.2 (slave1)

192.168.1.3 (slave2)

I'm running a spring boot microservice on another box (192.168.1.4) that is the driver program connecting to the remote spark cluster.

When I submit a task, it is picked up successfully on the spark cluster, but fails on a particular step with the following error and stacktrace.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$filter$1.f$1 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$filter$1
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2292)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My SparkConf is as follows:

```
new SparkConf()
.setAppName(spark_app_name)
.setMaster("spark://192.168.1.1:7077")
.setJars(new String[]{<path_to_my_spring_boot_fat_jar_on_each_of_spark_machines>});
```

The line on which it breaks is:

```
paginatedResults = sparkSqlContext.createDataFrame(filteredRdd, schema).toJSON().collectAsList();
```

specifically on org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectAsList(Dataset.scala:2793)

with the error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$filter$1.f$1 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$filter$1

This works when I run using standalone spark mode on my local, but fails on the remote cluster.

```
private void paginate(Dataset<Row> df, int startRow, int endRow) {
    // save schema to recreate data frame
    StructType schema = df.schema();

    // obtain row count and subtract for total row
    long rowCount = df.count() - 1L;

    // convert data frame to RDD and introduce a row index so we can filter results
    // by range
    JavaRDD<Row> totalRow = df.toJavaRDD().zipWithIndex().filter(x -> x._2 == 0).map(x -> x._1);
    JavaPairRDD<Row, Long> zippedRows = df.toJavaRDD().zipWithIndex().filter(x -> x._2() > 0);

    // filter rows by row index using the requested range (startRow, endRow), this
    // ensures we don't run out of memory
    JavaRDD<Row> filteredRdd = zippedRows.filter(pair -> pair._2 >= startRow && pair._2 <= endRow)
            .map(pair -> pair._1);

    // collect paginated results into a list of json objects
    paginatedResults = sparkSqlContext.createDataFrame(filteredRdd, schema).toJSON().collectAsList();

    totalRows = sparkSqlContext.createDataFrame(totalRow, schema).toJSON().collectAsList();
    // calculate last row
    lastRow = endRow >= rowCount ? rowCount : -1;
    log.info("Returning " + (endRow - startRow) + " no of rows for key:" + sparkKey);
}
```

This is how I'm running my spring boot driver service

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=<path_to_my_spring_boot_fat_jar_on_each_of_spark_machines>;
java -Dscheduler.enabled=false -Dspring.profiles.active=uat   -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -jar <path_to_my_spring_boot_fat_jar_on_the_driver_machine>
```

Any thoughts around what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607/java-lang-classcastexception-using-lambda-expressions-in-spark-job-on-remote-ser&ved=2ahUKEwjlrNyp6YjkAhVBmuAKHYJTCFsQjjgwAHoECAYQAg&usg=AOvVaw3kNfmTR1ZJNaeoeJo5bQ3y)

Comment: @Eugene thanks, I saw that link. If I'm not mistaken, it basically says I don't have to make any changes to make it run on the remote cluster? Not sure if it is actually recommending a solution.

Comment: re-reading it, does it mean that I need the jar which has Dataset and collectAsList() in the classpath? Which is basically the spark-core jar. Given that it is bundled as part of my fat jar and that the fat jar is on the classpath as set by sparkConf.setJars(), isn't this supposed to be working? Or do I need to specify the spark core jar also separately as  part of the setJars() API? @Holger could you please clarify?

Comment: That does seem as if Spark Standalone does not have access to the necessary jars.  I can't seem to find how you define the fat jar so the driver distributes it to executors. Can you open web UI and make sure that Environment tab has the jar included? I'd bet it does not.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I see my fat jar is on the classpath entries under the source "System classpath". I was actually able to narrow it down to this lambda expression that is failing -> JavaRDD<Row> totalRow = df.toJavaRDD().zipWithIndex().filter(x -> x._2 == 0).map(x -> x._1);

Comment: @JacekLaskowski without that lambda expression in my code, everything else works. I even replaced that lamba expression with a spark java api Function anonymous class and still got the same error. At this point, I'm not sure what to do. The spark versions on all the boxes are the same -> 2.11.12

Comment: @JacekLaskowski actually, after I moved to the anonymous function and made my class with it Serializable, I'm now getting a different error


This exact one -> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9219

I went through the mvn:dependency tree as recommended there and there were no different versions of spark on there.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I created a new question with my latest findings. Please let me know if I need to close this one. Here's thew new one -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565349/classcastexception-cannot-assign-instance-of-scala-collection-immutable-listse