# Apache Spark java.lang.ClassCastException when running forEachPartition in remote master node

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, delete-row, classcastexception, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Java microservice that connects to an Apache Spark cluster and uses Datastax Spark-Cassandra connector to persist data to an apache Cassandra DB cluster.

I have written the following method to delete data from a Cassandra table for a specific date range.

The exact code is shown below:

```
public void deleteData(String fromDate, String toDate) {


    SparkConf conf = sparkSession.sparkContext().getConf();
    CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(conf);

    Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("keyspace", CassandraProperties.KEYSPACE);
        put("table", CassandraProperties.ENERGY_FORECASTS);
    }}).load()
            .filter(col("timestamp")
                    .substr(1, 10)
                    .between(fromDate, toDate))
            .select("nodeid");


    df.foreachPartition(partition -> {
        Session session = connector.openSession();
        while (partition.hasNext()) {
            Row row = partition.next();
            session.execute("DELETE FROM " + CassandraProperties.KEYSPACE + "." + CassandraProperties.ENERGY_FORECASTS + " WHERE nodeid = '" + row.mkString() + "' AND timestamp >= '" + fromDate + "' AND timestamp <= '" + toDate + "'");
        }
        session.close();
    });
}
```

}

```
    @Bean
public SparkSession sparkSession() {
    return SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("SparkCassandraApp")
            .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host)
            .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", port)
            .config("spark.sql.caseSensitive", false)
            .master(master)
            .getOrCreate();
```

The code executes fine when run using a local spark master node ( `.master("local[*]")` option).

However, when I try to execute the same code while connecting to a remote spark master node, the following error occurs:

> Driver stacktrace:] with root cause java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$2.func$4 of
>   type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachPartitionFunction in
>   instance of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$2
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2293)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [pool-18-thread-1] INFO
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector - Disconnected
>   from Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster

**UPDATE 1**

It appears that what did the trick for me was adding the following line at the sparkSession configuration:

```
.config("spark.jars", "meter-service-1.0.jar")
```

This appears to provide the missing dependencies that prevented Spark from deserializing the lamda expression correctly at the remote nodes.

This is better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607/java-lang-classcastexception-using-lambda-expressions-in-spark-job-on-remote-ser)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassCastException using lambda expressions in spark job on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607/java-lang-classcastexception-using-lambda-expressions-in-spark-job-on-remote-ser)

Answer (score 1):

My JAVA is flaky but can you try to extract the lambda into a method?

```
public void deleteData(String fromDate, String toDate) {
    SparkConf conf = sparkSession.sparkContext().getConf();
    CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(conf);

    Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("keyspace", CassandraProperties.KEYSPACE);
        put("table", CassandraProperties.ENERGY_FORECASTS);
    }}).load()
        .filter(col("timestamp")
                .substr(1, 10)
                .between(fromDate, toDate))
        .select("nodeid");


    df.foreachPartition(new ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>() {
        public void call(Iterator<Row> partition) {
            Session session = connector.openSession();
            while (partition.hasNext()) {
                Row row = partition.next();
                session.execute("DELETE FROM " + CassandraProperties.KEYSPACE + "." + CassandraProperties.ENERGY_FORECASTS + " WHERE nodeid = '" + row.mkString() + "' AND timestamp >= '" + fromDate + "' AND timestamp <= '" + toDate + "'");
            }
            session.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That was my first though also, however when I try this I run into a java.io.NotSerializableException.