# Scala: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field Child1.myfun of type scala.Function1

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to take function name as a parameter in parent class so child class can set it. This variable will be used in one of the parent class' method.

```
abstract class Parent[T: TypeInformation] {
   val myfun: T => Unit

   // A different method uses myfun
}

class Child1 extends Parent[User] {
   val service = new Service()

   val myfun: User => Unit = service.callme
}

class Service {
   def callme(user: User) => Unit = {
      println("We are here for user")
   }
}
```

I'm new to scala but this looked okay. While compiler doesn't complain, I am getting run time exception and the job won't start:

```
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot instantiate user function.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:250)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:427)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createChainedOperator(OperatorChain.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.createOutputCollector(OperatorChain.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.<init>(OperatorChain.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:393)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field Child1.myfun of type scala.Function1 in instance of Child1
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2301)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2372)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2290)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2148)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1647)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2054)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1635)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2366)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2290)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2148)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1647)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2366)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2290)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2148)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1647)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2366)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2290)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2148)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1647)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2366)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2290)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2148)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1647)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:441)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:576)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:562)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:550)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:511)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:235)
    ... 11 more
```

Any idea how can I set the function name as variable value in child so parent can use it?

Comment: This is going through object serialization. Not sure if it is possible to serialize closures/functions this way. Is it possible to do something simpler?  (Note that you are not setting a "function name" to the variable, `myfun` contains the actual function itself).

Comment: Maybe an abstract `def myFun(t:T): Unit` that the subclass can implement would work? That way, the function becomes part of the class definition itself and does not need to be serialized as data.

Comment: Could it be that spark doesn't have the matching jar? I get serialization issues when the jars are missing or out of date. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607/java-lang-classcastexception-using-lambda-expressions-in-spark-job-on-remote-ser/28367602#28367602

Answer (score 5):

You are talking about passing function *names*, but what you're passing is the actual function itself. It looks like that doesn't survive serialization through flink.

An alternative encoding might be not using a function value at all, but a plain old method:

```
abstract class Parent[T: TypeInformation] {
   def myfun(t: T): Unit

   // A different method uses myfun
}

class Child1 extends Parent[User] {
   val service = new Service()

   def myfun(t: User): Unit = service.callme(t)
}

class Service {
   def callme(user: User) => Unit = {
      println("We are here for user")
   }
}
```

If this doesn't work out of the box, it should at least give you a clearer error message (possibly about the availability of `Service` on the class path.

Fixing that issue might then allow you to go back to your previous encoding