Unable to train SynapseML LightGBMClassifier on Spark
I have a 10 node Spark cluster and my job does the following,

Read parquet files from GCS bucket
Perform feature engineering, train/test split on the data
Use SynapseML LightGBMClassifier to train the data

I encounter error during lightgbm.fit operation. I have provided the code snippet for spark conf & also the error message. Job works if spark is run on "local" mode, hence wondering if it has to do with distributed processing.
Your help in identifying the root cause is greatly appreciated.
Spark config
configs={
            "spark.jars": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-lib/gcs/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.9.jar",
            "spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl": "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS",
            "spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl": "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem",
            "spark.jars.packages": "com.microsoft.azure:synapseml_2.12:0.11.4-spark3.3",
            "spark.jars.repositories": "https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven",
            "spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled": "true",
            "spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields": "10000",
            "spark.shuffle.service.enabled": "true",
            "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "true",
            "spark.driver.memory": "100g",
            "spark.driver.maxResultSize": "50g",
            "spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruningFallbackOnException": "true",
            "spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors": "1",
            "spark.broadcast.blockSize": "100m",
            "spark.broadcast.compress": "true",
            "spark.broadcast.numRetries": "3",
            "spark.broadcast.checksum": "true",
            "spark.broadcast.retries": "5",
            "spark.broadcast.timeout": "1200",
            "spark.task.maxFailures": "4",
            "spark.serializer": "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",
            "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max": "1g",
            "spark.rpc.message.maxSize": "1024",
            "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-Xss1G -Dscala.usejavacp=true",
            "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-Xss1G -Dscala.usejavacp=true"
        }

Error message
24/06/07 15:20:42 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 13) (10.127.0.28 executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2076)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2039)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1293)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2512)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2419)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

24/06/07 15:20:42 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
24/06/07 15:20:42 ERROR LightGBMClassifier: {"protocolVersion":"0.0.1","method":"fit","libraryName":"SynapseML","errorMessage":"org.apache.spark.SparkException","errorType":"org.apache.spark.SparkException","className":"class com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMClassifier","libraryVersion":"0.11.4-spark3.3","modelUid":"LightGBMClassifier_3c41d40e36b8"}
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 18) (10.127.0.28 executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2076)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2039)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1293)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2512)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2419)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2238)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2259)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2278)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.core.utils.ClusterUtil$.getNumRowsPerPartition(ClusterUtil.scala:50)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.calculateRowStatistics(LightGBMBase.scala:518)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.trainOneDataBatch(LightGBMBase.scala:425)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.$anonfun$train$2(LightGBMBase.scala:62)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.logging.SynapseMLLogging.logVerb(SynapseMLLogging.scala:163)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.logging.SynapseMLLogging.logVerb$(SynapseMLLogging.scala:160)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMClassifier.logVerb(LightGBMClassifier.scala:27)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.logging.SynapseMLLogging.logFit(SynapseMLLogging.scala:153)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.logging.SynapseMLLogging.logFit$(SynapseMLLogging.scala:152)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMClassifier.logFit(LightGBMClassifier.scala:27)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.train(LightGBMBase.scala:64)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.train$(LightGBMBase.scala:36)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMClassifier.train(LightGBMClassifier.scala:27)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMClassifier.train(LightGBMClassifier.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2076)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2039)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1293)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2512)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2419)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
24/06/07 15:20:42 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.2 in stage 13.0 (TID 19) (10.127.0.28 executor 0): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)

 Exception during training - An error occurred while calling o258.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 18) (10.127.0.28 executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2076)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2039)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1293)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2512)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2419)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2238)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2259)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2278)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.core.utils.ClusterUtil$.getNumRowsPerPartition(ClusterUtil.scala:50)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.calculateRowStatistics(LightGBMBase.scala:518)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.trainOneDataBatch(LightGBMBase.scala:425)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.$anonfun$train$2(LightGBMBase.scala:62)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.logging.SynapseMLLogging.logVerb(SynapseMLLogging.scala:163)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.logging.SynapseMLLogging.logVerb$(SynapseMLLogging.scala:160)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMClassifier.logVerb(LightGBMClassifier.scala:27)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.logging.SynapseMLLogging.logFit(SynapseMLLogging.scala:153)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.logging.SynapseMLLogging.logFit$(SynapseMLLogging.scala:152)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMClassifier.logFit(LightGBMClassifier.scala:27)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.train(LightGBMBase.scala:64)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMBase.train$(LightGBMBase.scala:36)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMClassifier.train(LightGBMClassifier.scala:27)
    at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMClassifier.train(LightGBMClassifier.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2076)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2039)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1293)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2512)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2419)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more


What is reproduction? See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607 https://github.com/apache/hudi/issues/8791 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210723
