# Java 8 compatible no error given spark version needed

Tags: java, apache-spark, deployment, apache-spark-standalone

I am dealing with searching suitable versions for java and spark. I am new for spark. I changed a lot version and got error for all. So I am here. I just want to deploy spark in my local in windows. When I run master and workers I want my code to run in master and among workers.

I was using Java 17 and finally dropped to java 8. Now spark version is problematic. As for now, I was downloaded spark 2.4.8 with scala 2.12 and Java 8. Now the error is about serialVersionUID etc.

```
23/09/30 14:34:16 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.                  java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEndpointRef; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -4186747031772874359, local class serialVersionUID = 6257082371135760434
```

And also my best trying was with Java 8 (always) and spark 2.4.6. In this version I could see in localhost:8080 the application is completed but my application was dying becasue there were SerializedLamda exception. Idk why this exception occurs. I wrote another code which doesnt use lambdas then works. But the given code throws exception.

Please give me best version for spark deployment in local with real time streaming.

Here the code;

```
public class Demo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4186747031772874359L;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext("spark://192.168.1.158:7077", "TheAnalysis");
        JavaRDD<String> rawDataRDD = sparkContext.textFile("src/main/resources/WorldCup/WorldCupPlayers.csv");
        //all players
        JavaRDD<Player> playersRDD = rawDataRDD.map(line -> new Player(line.split(",", -1)));

//        playersRDD.foreach(players -> System.out.println(players.getPlayerName())); // print user name

        //MESSI DUNYA KUPASINDA KAC MAC YAPTI?
        JavaRDD<Player> messiRDD = playersRDD.filter(player -> player.getPlayerName().equalsIgnoreCase("MESSI"));
        System.out.println("Messi dünya kupasında " + messiRDD.count() + " maç yaptı");

        //Tüm oyuncular dünya kupasında kaç maç yaptı?
        JavaPairRDD<String, String> mapPairRDD = playersRDD.mapToPair(player -> new Tuple2<>(player.getPlayerName(), player.getMatchID()));
//        mapPairRDD.foreach((player) -> System.out.println(player._1 + " -- " + player._2));

        JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>> groupPlayer = mapPairRDD.groupByKey();
        groupPlayer.foreach(player -> System.out.println(player._1 + "--" + player._2));

        JavaRDD<ModifiedPlayer> modifiedPlayerRDD = groupPlayer.map(player -> new ModifiedPlayer(player._1, Iterators.size(player._2.iterator())));
        modifiedPlayerRDD.foreach(modifiedPlayer -> System.out.println(modifiedPlayer.getPlayerName() + " : " + modifiedPlayer.getMatchSize()));
        long count = modifiedPlayerRDD.count();
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

A lot of spark versions tried but all failed.

Comment: And also I got error when worker node is connected. Application is running while only master is alive after I create Worker node then running application becomes killed and then gives SerializedLamda exception in scala 2.11

Comment: Why 2.4.x ?  Try to use 3.5 directly.  2.4.x is 4+ years old (last fix version was 2 years ago).  The specific error is likely different versions of the libraries on the executors (or potentially different versions from classpath/loading issues), all library versions must have matching scala versions and must be compiled with a class version that matches your jvm version.  Trying to using versions of libraries that are newer than the ones shipped with Spark can also be very risky and introduce such issues.  Lastly use maven or similar directly to do dev, don't use jars directly.

Comment: Sir, I did what you said. Again I got an error.I commented a part of code, run again. Finally I found where code crashes. It does work when I commented  messiRDD.count() part. I thought count function doesnt work. It was thrwoing exception. But when I only run this count code it still works. Here the working code. --"JavaRDD<String> wordRdd = sparkContext.textFile("src/main/resources/dataset.txt");
        System.out.println(wordRdd.count());" -- Whats the problem. I think my code is mistaken above.

Comment: The exception is Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) (192.168.1.158 executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD

Comment: please put the exception in a code block in your question so people can see it without expanding comments

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'd question why you use RDD's instead of DataFrame/Set, these kinds of serialisation issues are typically due to something in the function not being serializable - even when they look like they should be (Scala wise Seq could easily be a Stream which is not serializable despite the interface seemingly being so).

In this case perhaps Player has the issue and is not Serializable.  Instead of trying messiRDD.count, try playersRDD.count and see if it also fails with the same error.  If so then Player itself is not serializeable (or contains other non-serializable fields).

If not then you'll have to swap lambdas for class instances like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32403464/1028537).

Comment: Yeah but the main problem is it work when I run local but when I set master as spark://192.168.1.158:7077 Idk difference of RDD or dataframe etc. But in the code specified class is Serialiazeble and work fine with local.

Comment: Look let me tell you steps what I do. First ı open 2 terminal cmd one for master one for worker. I wrote spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master for master. And I wrote spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.1.158:7077 for worker. Then localhost:8080 see worker successfully connected to master. Then I run spark app given above it raises error only when it is not specified as local. I installed scala 2.13, Java 8 and spark 3.5.0 Is there something missed? Even I couldnt find a clear and very simple tutorial for spark deploying.

Comment: Btw, I do all in my personal computer. I just wanted to test spark deployment in my local. So I do nothing for workers just execute as a node. I would know when I run spark code in my master, spark will automatically share data among workers. Am I wrong?