# SparkConnectGrpcException while working with Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Spark Connect to connect with my remote spark cluster and execute this block of code. Seems like I might be missing something. Here is IPython Notebook. I am using PySpark and To Run the remote server I am using this command on the server end:

```bash
/opt/bitnami/spark/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.0 --master spark://spark-master-0.spark-headless.spark-operator.svc.cluster.local:7077
```

**The Notebook:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import time

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
from pyspark.sql.types import * 

from datetime import datetime, date
from pyspark.sql import Row


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("My App").remote("sc://HOST:PORT").getOrCreate()
```

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=2, b=3., c='string2', d=date(2000, 2, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=4, b=5., c='string3', d=date(2000, 3, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
])
df.collect()
```

**Output:**

```
[Row(a=1, b=2.0, c='string1', d=datetime.date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
 Row(a=2, b=3.0, c='string2', d=datetime.date(2000, 2, 1), e=datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
 Row(a=4, b=5.0, c='string3', d=datetime.date(2000, 3, 1), e=datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))]
```

```py
df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load('breast-cancer.csv')
df2 = df.select(df.columns[0:4])
df2.show(n=5)
```

**Output:**

```
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
|      id|diagnosis|radius_mean|texture_mean|
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  842302|        M|      17.99|       10.38|
|  842517|        M|      20.57|       17.77|
|84300903|        M|      19.69|       21.25|
|84348301|        M|      11.42|       20.38|
|84358402|        M|      20.29|       14.34|
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

only showing top 5 rows

But when I do:

```py
df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load('breast-cancer.csv')
df.collect()
```

or,

```py
df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load('breast-cancer.csv')
df.limit(5).toPandas()
```

**Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SparkConnectGrpcException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 2
      1 df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load('breast-cancer.csv')
----> 2 df.collect()

File ~/Documents/workstation/jupyter-lab/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/dataframe.py:1645, in DataFrame.collect(self)
   1643     raise Exception("Cannot collect on empty session.")
   1644 query = self._plan.to_proto(self._session.client)
-> 1645 table, schema = self._session.client.to_table(query)
   1647 schema = schema or from_arrow_schema(table.schema, prefer_timestamp_ntz=True)
   1649 assert schema is not None and isinstance(schema, StructType)

File ~/Documents/workstation/jupyter-lab/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:858, in SparkConnectClient.to_table(self, plan)
    856 req = self._execute_plan_request_with_metadata()
    857 req.plan.CopyFrom(plan)
--> 858 table, schema, _, _, _ = self._execute_and_fetch(req)
    859 assert table is not None
    860 return table, schema

File ~/Documents/workstation/jupyter-lab/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1282, in SparkConnectClient._execute_and_fetch(self, req, self_destruct)
   1279 schema: Optional[StructType] = None
   1280 properties: Dict[str, Any] = {}
-> 1282 for response in self._execute_and_fetch_as_iterator(req):
   1283     if isinstance(response, StructType):
   1284         schema = response

File ~/Documents/workstation/jupyter-lab/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1263, in SparkConnectClient._execute_and_fetch_as_iterator(self, req)
   1261                     yield from handle_response(b)
   1262 except Exception as error:
-> 1263     self._handle_error(error)

File ~/Documents/workstation/jupyter-lab/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1502, in SparkConnectClient._handle_error(self, error)
   1489 """
   1490 Handle errors that occur during RPC calls.
   1491 
   (...)
   1499 Throws the appropriate internal Python exception.
   1500 """
   1501 if isinstance(error, grpc.RpcError):
-> 1502     self._handle_rpc_error(error)
   1503 elif isinstance(error, ValueError):
   1504     if "Cannot invoke RPC" in str(error) and "closed" in str(error):

File ~/Documents/workstation/jupyter-lab/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1538, in SparkConnectClient._handle_rpc_error(self, rpc_error)
   1536             info = error_details_pb2.ErrorInfo()
   1537             d.Unpack(info)
-> 1538             raise convert_exception(info, status.message) from None
   1540     raise SparkConnectGrpcException(status.message) from None
   1541 else:

SparkConnectGrpcException: (org.apache.spark.SparkException) Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 62.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 62.0 (TID 106) (172.31.30.154 executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2096)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2060)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1347)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2486)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2257)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2606)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2457)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2257)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:509)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:467)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkE...
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the version of Spark you are using ? The package you have mentioned `spark-connect_2.12:3.5.0`, may not be compatible with the version of Spark.  Also `sc.version` should match with the `spark-submit --version`

Comment: I am using bitnami docker image for spark, spark connect is started from the same docker image from the /sbin/start-spark-connect.sh

Comment: You should focus on "java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD". It seems like an error related to the usage of Jars. I don't know how you set up the environment but you should check [this](https://github.com/apache/hudi/issues/8340) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607/java-lang-classcastexception-using-lambda-expressions-in-spark-job-on-remote-ser/28367602#28367602). It may help

Comment: I am not submitting any jars. I think spark connect should take care of it as its an abstraction.
Here is my kubernetes statefulset script: [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/F0C0u64u)